# How do I access typeof Class with generic

Tags: typescript

```
class Alpha {
  static create<T extends typeof Alpha>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    const v = new Alpha();
    return v as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}

class Beta extends Alpha {}

const a = Alpha.create(); // returns Alpha
const b = Beta.create(); // returns Beta
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCIAcAWZoG8CwAoa0IBcx8BLYaYAJwFMiqAeAFWioA98qA7AExnwE8EVAPYAzOIhQA%20ABT4kxCAC5oDAJTKAkhwJgOwKgwH0Gk9Nly5gQ7fmgA3aAF5oHKgHdxyMNNUBucxbU%20ACuFBz20JDQWjp6BkaMkv440AC%202OlY2KCQMABCVITMbJw8nijomdnWBJFO5WAAdJQ07D6%200AD0ndBBodoN1TbQAEb1BYTN1LTtXT19YfmFYEA)

Now I had to add in a generic to `Alpha` and `Beta` and I get this:

```
class Alpha<T = string> {
  static create<T extends typeof Alpha>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    const v = new Alpha();
    return v as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}

class Beta<T = number> extends Alpha<T> {}

const a = Alpha.create(); // returns Alpha<unknown>
const b = Beta.create(); // returns Beta<unknown>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCIAcAWYA8AVaBeaEAuATgJYB2A5gHzQDeAsAFDS55h5HDTAECmr3G0bgA883EgBMYeAJ4JuAewBmcRCgoAKPEiIQAXNHQBKfQEkS%20MCWDd0s-uip1GTTvPN5oAN2zQS3AO4qyGDqhgDcDC7QPHgArgQkXtCQ0GYWVjZ2GBQRzgC%20DAX0DKCQMABC3CwCOCSxALYARtwEVMKiEjDwwdk0RSVu%20Mk%203SgAdFy8oqFh0AD0c9FV8eZBKKixJADWJPL%20JBQD7tCNPpUsEzx8M-OLMSsVVWibO3sHQA)

Here I'd expect to get `Alpha<string>` and `Beta<number>` but for some reason `InstanceType<T>` is not activating the "default" / "assigned" value for generics from the classes.

Is it possible to pass in a generic and have a shared method like `.create()` above where both classes return their respective instances, but with defaulted generics?

I've also tried `T['prototype']` and didn't get any luck.

I was hoping there'd be a way I could create a custom `InstanceType` but I don't think that's possible. Here's the one included with TypeScript. I don't think it can access the generics.

```
type InstanceType<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` applies to an *instance* of the class, and can be different for every instance.  Your method `create` is `static` and therefore not tied to any instance of the class, so it doesn't inherit any generic `T` from the class.

`<T = string>` is just a default value.  It doesn't actually limit the possible values of `T` in any way.  So your `T` becomes `unknown` on a static method call.  Both `Alpha` and `Beta` can have any value of `T` and you have no way of knowing what the value of `T` will be on the instance that you create with `create()` unless you explicitly pass a generic argument.

Here is what it looks like if we pass an explicit generic parameter to `create()`:

```
class Alpha<T = string> {
  // I'm giving this generic a different name to denote that it is unrelated to `T`
  static create<C = string>(): Alpha<C> {
    return new Alpha<C>();
  }
}

const a = Alpha.create<number>(); // returns Alpha<number>
const b = Alpha.create<[]>(); // returns Alpha<[]>
const c = Alpha.create(); // return Alpha<string>
```

You can use this utility type to get the `T` value from an `Alpha`:

```
type AlphaType<A> = A extends Alpha<infer T> ? T : never;

type A = AlphaType<typeof a> // number
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCIAcAWYA8AVaBeaEAuATgJYB2A5gHzQDeAsAFDTQD0z0AkgOQC20ZRAN1JloeJERhkApiSnFg0MNAAmRAGZq5MvNBJhuU0QHsVMo3kNiwOojZgBXEgSngLy49AAG6Twyb5rIgVgZ2spVABhbFxCYQoACgBKAC44RBRIqjpGJmhnPHsCEl0pAHc05DQIhMSAbj9oAF8GZvoGYCMSfEVo%20EqAOhCpMNQSe24AIzka2pY2fMKuioyxyen2zu6J3vSwQdCLVABtAF0ZubypAqKYPozTig2unQUcO72hsKTZ1kvr4veqHwxHIjza9DwAE8EIZ3uhoeFYFQ3tApAAPCwkZS3XaoUiaAjQdBUAD8ROgqVkAjk9XBUJhcB2lXhMNQ9KkRjUiiov1WUwIQA)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply constrain `T` in `Alpha` and every subclasses to specific type:

```
class Alpha<T extends string = string> {
  static create<T extends typeof Alpha>(this: T): InstanceType<T> {
    return new this() as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}

class Beta<T extends number = number> extends Alpha {}

const a = Alpha.create(); // returns Alpha<string>
const b = Beta.create(); // returns Beta<number>
```